# Unable to call service from ESB

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

We are able to call web service from postman or custom request generator. However, while connecting using IBM Integration bus we are getting below exception. Can some one help with this error.

Exception below:

> "Web Service request has detected a SOCKET error whilst invoking a web
>   service located at host &1, on port &2, on path &3."
>   "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: PKIX path
>   building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException:
>   PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal
>   cause is:   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The
>   certificate issued by CN=VeriSign Universal Root Certification
>   Authority, OU="(c) 2008 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only",
>   OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US is not trusted;
>   internal cause is: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException:
>   Certificate chaining error"

Comment: Where is the code generating those error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve this problem, you should add the certificate into your trust store.

To setup the truststore on broker :

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac56640_.htm

To retrieve the certificate of the service you are calling, you can ask for it to your contact, or you can just go to the ?wsdl page and directly save the certificate from chrome

PS : If it works for other tools, it is simply because IIB refuse all the untrusted connexions by default, while some other tool allow it.